# Find two subgroups of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and an isomorphism between them that is not a homeomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Find two subgroups $G_1$ and $G_2$ of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$, and an isomorphism $f:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ which fails to be a homeomorphism. The metric on $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the induced metric from $\mathbb{C}^4$. This is an exercise in *The Geometry of Discrete Groups*. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find an infinite cyclic subgroup that has the discrete topology (a certain group of upper unitriangular matrices will work) and an infinite cyclic subgroup whose closure is homeomorphic to a circle (a certain group of diagonal matrices will work).